# User Experience Between App Installation and First Time App Opening

Tags: mobile-application, installation

I am interested in finding out key reasons behind drop offs between Install App stage to First Open Stage. So, usually if I get 100 installs then approx 60-65 go to the first open stage ( as per Firebase data) Why does this drop off happen and is there anyway to retarget those people who have installed the app but not opened it. Thank you.

Comment: From personal experience: some of them may have installed it because they might want to use it at some point, but not just yet. They saw the app, thought it may be interesting at some point, but have no use for it at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Because the First impression went wrong. User onboarding is the process of helping new users understand and experience how your product is going to help them achieve their goal. In your case, they might be don't know how to use it/ what are the benefits in your app.

**9 best practices and strategies for perfecting your onboarding process**

1. Interview users to understand why they’re coming to your product and where they came from
2. Define what ‘success’ looks like for each of your customer use cases
3. Create and use hooks to get customers invested in your tool
4. Break items down and leave something to be discovered
5. Keep momentum by setting expectations and showing their progress
6. Use progressive profiling and reduce the friction for getting started
7. Build inflows that connect teams and create an ‘onboarding leader’
8. Create educational and aspirational content to give hands-off support
9. Make sure you have visibility into when users are dropping off